# "Promised to someone" meaning

Tags: word-usage, meaning, meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning, word-meaning

I've been listening to many songs and came across these two lyrics

> Oh, goddamn.
> My pain fits in the palm of your freezing hand.
> Taking mine, but it's been **promised** to another
> (Ivy by Taylor Swift)

> He told me that the life of my dreams
> Would be **promised** and someday be mine
> (We don't talk about Bruno by V.A.)

I kinda get that in both cases, the word "promised" here means something related to marriage or engagement. However, I can't find any dictionaries or websites that prove this. Is what I understand true?

Comment: You can promise anything (tangible or intangible) to anyone at all. The two things promised are very different  in your texts. One is pain and the other is a life of dreams.

Comment: BTW, the phrase, "being promised in marriage", is a common in English, particularly in literature predating 1900, though it's still often used: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=promised+in+marriage&year_start=1600&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can *promise to do* something (eg "*I promise to behave*"), but you can also *promise something to someone* (eg "*A gift was promised me*"). As well as that, 'promised' can be an adjective to describe something or someone that has been the direct object of a promise (eg "*the promised land*").

If something has been promised to someone, it is like it has been reserved for that person for a future time.

'Promised' is also intrinsically linked to marriage and commitment within relationships. A person who is engaged is said to be 'promised' to their partner. This is the kind of use that the song lyrics allude to but, like a lot of lyrics or poetry, it doesn't really reflect everyday speech.